# How to run a Cordova project from already running Cordova project?

Tags: cordova

I m building a Cordova project I want to run another app on clicking a button on the running app. please help.

Answer (score 1):

Check this plugin:

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Custom-URL-scheme

You can add a custom scheme in your second app, and open it like an hyperlink

In your second app, in console

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-customurlscheme --variable URL_SCHEME=mysecondapp
```

And in the first one, add this to your button to call the second

```
<a href="mysecondapp://">Open my app</a>
```

If you want to open another app, that is not yours, you have to check if this have url scheme

```
<a href="geo:38.897096,-77.036545">Open Maps</a>
<a href="twitter://">Open twitter</a>
```